# Operations Dashboard - How to insert a line break into summary widget trailing text?

Tags: operations-dashboard

In a ArcGIS Online Ops Dashboard Operation View, I have a summary widget configured to show a count of features like so:

**6,087 new features added**

...where 6,087 is the count of my features and " new features added" is my trailing text that I add into the configuration.

What I would like it to look like is:

**6,087 new
 features added**

In other words, I want a line break in it. I've tried adding these into my trailing string in the widget settings:

```
\n
<br>
&lt;br&gt;
%26lt;br%26gt;
```

...and they all just come out raw. Also, I've tried adding in the breaks in both the Ops Dash GUI app and I edited the Operation View JSON directly in AGO Assistant. Anyone got a trick to get a line break in there? Not even sure if it's possible.

A colleague jogged my brain and got me to look at the HTML output for that element, which looks like so:

```
<text dominant-baseline="middle" class="label" fill="#f79646" text-anchor="middle" x="189.5" style="font-size: 20px;">6,087 total %26lt;br%26gt;dead meters</text>
```

So, it appears that my text all gets wrapped up in the `<text>` tag, which would explain why none of my HTML takes. I'm beginning to think this would be more work than it's worth to accomplish.